# Prove that there are infinitely many real numbers.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, number-theory

Here it goes:

Assume that there is an upper bound first for the set $\mathbb{R}$ let $\alpha = \sup \mathbb{R}$  So assume $\alpha = \sup \mathbb{R}$ Therefore $\alpha \ge x$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$ but because $\alpha = \sup \mathbb{R}$ we also have $\alpha \ge x + 1$ this implies $\alpha - 1 \ge x$, but realise that $\alpha - 1 < \alpha$ and because $x \le \alpha - 1$ this implies that $\alpha - 1$ is $\sup \mathbb{R}$ which is a contradiction. Assume there is a lower bound for the set $\mathbb{R}$. Let $\psi = \inf \mathbb{R}$ this means, $\psi \le x$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Also because it is a lower bound $\psi \le x - 1$ in the same way $\psi + 1 \le x$ and $\psi + 1 > \psi$ so $\psi + 1 = \inf \mathbb{R}$ which is a contradiction. Hence it is unbounded below and above, hence $\mathbb{R}$ has infinite elements within the set, it is not finite.

Is my proof correct? How could it be improved?

Comment: What construction of $\mathbf{R}$ are you using ?...

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I feel like this is a good argument to show that $\Bbb{N}$ is unbounded above. Wouldn't it be easier to show that $\Bbb{R}$ has infinitely many real numbers by the mere citation that $\Bbb{N} \subset \Bbb{R}$?

Comment: Are choice sequences real numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is wrong with your proof, but I have a couple pointers for improvements. As I mentioned in the comments, you can use this argument to show $\Bbb{N}$ is unbounded above and has infinitely many elements. Thus, $\Bbb{R}$ has infinitely many elements because $\Bbb{N} \subset \Bbb{R}$. If you insist on keeping your proof as is, you can at least remove everything about $\Bbb{R}$ not being bounded below, because showing $\Bbb{R}$ is not bounded above is sufficient for showing $\Bbb{R}$ has infinitely many elements. Additionally, you can take a look at this proof of Cantor's: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument. I think it's a pretty slick proof and it gives you the neat fact that $\Bbb{R}$ is a "size" of infinity even larger than $\Bbb{N}$, in addition to giving you the result you are after.

Comment: From your comment above , (+1) btw, I couldnt use $mathbb{N}$ argument because I also have to prove that $\mathbb{R}$ is unbounded **below..** thanks for clearing it up!

Comment: @Amad27 Ah, I did not know that. In the future please included everything you need to show, and what you can/can't use in your post. At any rate, glad I was able to help :)

Comment: Thanks! So the proof was all valid?

Comment: It looks good to me; it is sound and valid. The only complaint I had was the redundancy of parts of the proof, but it may have been required due to what you were allowed to use in getting your result.